# Why is MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.DeserializeExtraElement Throwing a Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

A Bson element name has changed in one of our documents. I am attempting to make the change backward compatible by having the old element name serialized into the ExtraElements property of our entity so that I can map it to the new property. I followed an implementation example here, http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#a-member-is-renamed, to no avail. I've tried explicitly registering the map class. I changed the ExtraElements type to a BsonDocument instead of an IDictionary. I've tried private backers, static constructors, etc. For some reason, I keep getting a null reference exception when when MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer.DeserializeExtraElement is invoked and I have no idea why.

This is the call

```
var cacheEvent = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<CacheEventDocument>(cacheEventDocument);
```

It should be noted that the CacheEventDocument class does derive from a base class. However, I have tried registering the class with BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap and I have decorated the base class with the BsonKnownTypes attribute as well. Nothing rectifies this null reference exception.

```
static CacheEventDocument()
    {
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<CacheEventDocument>(cm =>
            {
                cm.AutoMap();
                cm.SetExtraElementsMember(cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.ExtraElements));
            });
    }
```

I know, I need to verify whether the class is already registered. I haven't bothered with that yet. I am just trying to get the deserialization to work so that I can map the old field to the new one.

```
public void EndInit()
    {
        object coaterSiteName;

        if (!this.ExtraElements.TryGetValue("RoutingSiteName", out coaterSiteName)) { return; }

        this.CoaterSiteName = (string)coaterSiteName;

        // remove the Name element so that it doesn't get persisted back to the database
        this.ExtraElements.Remove("RoutingSiteName");
    }

public BsonDocument ExtraElements { get; set; }
```

Is there something else I need to do?